# Negative Error Term in Regression Model

Tags: regression, error

In regression analysis, an error term is included to indicate the uncertainty of a model:
$Y_{i} = \beta_{0}+\beta_{1}x_{i}+\epsilon_{i}$

Is it appropriate to also write $Y_{i} = \beta_{0}+\beta_{1}x_{i}-\epsilon_{i}?$ Will the interpretation of the error term change?

Thank you.

Comment: Pretty much nothing changes, but what do you hope to accomplish by doing this?

Comment: A pupil coded a regression model with a minus epsilon term. Is this incorrect?

Comment: It is fine. Here $\epsilon$ is still a signed vertical distance from a random $Y$ at a given $X$ to its conditional mean. The only difference is that when $Y$ is below the mean, the sign is positive.